# how to allign images vertically inside a div without any space between them

Tags: html, css

i was going through this tutorial, to allign two images inside a dive vertically so that there is no space between them, please take a look
http://mynag.kopiblog.com/2012/11/28/solved-remove-space-below-an-image-in-div-when-vertically-align/

i wrote my code like this

```
<head>
<style type=”text/css”>
.imgclass
{
 background-color:#1122CC;
 text-align:center;
}
img
{
 display:block; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class=”imgclass”>
<img src=”pictop.jpg”>
 </div>
<div>
<img src=”picbottom.jpg”>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but it didnt workrd as shown in the second pic shown in the link i specified.
What am i doing wrong here.
i want them as two pics alined vertically without any space.

please help

Comment: you have `”` you really should change them to `"`

Comment: both are double quotes right? please specify line num

Comment: Try modifying http://jsfiddle.net/682tt/

Comment: did you try .imgclass { padding:0; line-height:0px; margin:0px;}

Comment: Code is working fine for me in chrome. which browser this problem came?

Comment: @Robin One are smart quotes (`”`) the other isn't (`"`), mostly programmers don't use smart quotes. Sometimes smart quotes can interfere with how code is rendered.

Comment: yes i did, but not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please replace your quotes with the right ones, `“` is not `"`.

The code is missing doctype and opening html-tag.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .imgclass
        {
            background-color:#1122CC;
            text-align:center;
        }
        img
        {
            display:block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="imgclass">
    <img src="http://image.tutorvista.com/cms/images/38/square1.jpg">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://image.tutorvista.com/cms/images/38/square1.jpg">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your result should look like this:
http://pbrd.co/1qt52ku

Tested in Chrome. Other browser may need fixes via `line-height`, `margin`, and `padding`.